# Configuring Play Framework with Spark

Tags: scala, playframework, apache-spark

How do you configure Play such that it can run with the Spark cluster? Currently I have a web framework using Play but also connects to a Spark cluster. When I run `spark-shell` I get the following, which is good:

```
SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20130813222026-0026
Client$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20130813222026-0026/0 on worker-20130808012122-42908 with 16 cores
SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20130813222026-0026/8 on host with 16 cores, 8.0 GB RAM
Client$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20130813222026-0026/0 is now RUNNING
```

... etc.

But when I try to run `play start` I don't get the above message (indicating that I am running Spark locally and not on the cluster). Any ideas on the correct configurations to make this work?

Comment: The logging configuration may have made the logs silent. Could you verify from the Spark Master web UI that the SparkContext in the play application is connecting to it (spark master)?

Comment: Yeah on the Spark master's web UI nothing is listed under "Running Applications".

Comment: Are you initializing your SparkContext with the address of your cluster?